# clang-tidy: Analyze file with multiple errors

Tags: clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

Is it possible to analyze a C/C++ file in `clang-tidy`, while ignoring its syntax/compilation errors?

I have a very big file that has several compilation errors, but I still want to analyze it with `clang-tidy`.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
20 warnings and 20 errors generated.
Error while processing <myfile.c>
error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [clang-diagnostic-error]
```

I saw that in a smaller file, it is possible to have some syntax errors, but still, issues like index past the end of the array are displayed.

Is there a way to still have my file to be analyzed, despite the errors (like increasing the number of possible errors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may instruct clang-tidy to continue processing errors by applying `-ferror-limit=0` to the compilation flags, that is, add the following to clang-tidy command line:

`-extra-arg=-ferror-limit=0`

The default value for `-ferror-limit` is indeed 20.

Alternatively, you may want to set the limit to a higher number of your choice, rather than disabling the limitation completely.

Note that if you are using the `run-clang-tidy.py` script, rather than `clang-tidy` directly, you'll need version 5.0 for `-extra-arg` parameter support.